# Backup of PostgreSQL database design - without data

Tags: postgresql, backup

I have tried to find a way to backup my database design without including the data stored in the database. Actually, one might say that I want to have a file that holds all "CREATE Scripts" in the database. Ideally, this file could be used to recreate the database (with no data of course).

How to avoid data in a database backup?

I am using pgAdmin 4.1.3 and PostgreSQL 9.6.

Comment: click "only schema" on backup

Comment: [`pg_dump` with `--schema-only` option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html).

Answer (score 74):

You can use this from psql(terminal):

```
pg_dump -s databasename > file.dump
```

from pg_dump documentation the "-s" dump only the object definitions (schema), not data.

[pg_dump documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html)

Comment: I am rather new to PostgreSQL and has accessed databases only using pgAdmin. So how to open a command interpreter that will accept the 'pg_dump' command? (The database is not on my PC, but on some remote server.)

Comment: is it a linux server? what operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 7.

Comment: @Helge In my installation it is here: `C:/Program Files (x86)/pgAdmin 4/v1/runtime/pg_dump.exe`

Comment: you can download the Postgre SQL from https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads to run  `pg_dump` command

Answer (score 24):

```
pg_dump --host localhost --port 5432 --username "userName" --schema-only --verbose --file "file path" "db_dev_local"
```

Comment: Explaining what the command does and why the given options were selected would make this answer more informative and useful.

Comment: The example is incorrect.  If you use the POSIX-style options with double-dash then you need to use the `=` symbol as well, e.g. `--username=postgres`.  Space is used with the single dash options, e.g. `-U postgres`.

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR: Set `--schema-only` with `pg_dump`.

The `pg_dump` utility is distributed with Postgres in the `bin` directory.  The utility accepts many [options as documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html), and the format is:

```
pg_dump <options> <database-name>
```

To answer specifically the question here, open a Command Prompt window (Shell in *nix), and navigate to the Postgres `bin` directory.  Then issue the following command (Windows syntax shown):

```
> set DB_NAME=mydatabase
> pg_dump.exe --username=postgres --schema-only %DB_NAME% >%DB_NAME%-schema.sql
```

The `DB_NAME` environment variable is purely for convenience, and the name can be inlined for simplicity.

The `--username` switch is required in most cases, as you are probably not logged in to your OS as a valid Postgres user.

The `--schema-only` switch indicates that you only want the DDL statements, without the actual data.

The `>%DATABASE_NAME%-schema.sql` portion redirects the output from the console to a file named `%DATABASE_NAME%-schema.sql`, in this example "mydatabase-schema.sql".

The produced file is a valid SQL script, which can be executed via any valid client in order to recreate all the objects.

Here are a couple of other useful examples:

I usually prefix MATERIALIZED VIEWs with `mv_`, so to dump the definitions for only the relations that start with "mv_*" I use:

```
> pg_dump --username=postgres --schema-only --table=mv_* %DB_NAME% >%DB_NAME%-matviews.sql
```

Use multiple `--table=` arguments for multiple patterns.

To script only the POST-DATA objects, e.g. indexes, triggers, etc., use `--section=post-data`

```
> pg_dump --username=postgres --section=post-data %DB_NAME% >%DB_NAME%-post-data.sql
```

This assumes default host, port, authentication, etc.  To specify non-default settings refer to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html)

Answer (score 5):

Step on the database -< Tools ->Backup

then Dump Options

check the Only schema to be true

[image]

Comment: Hi! Do we know where this backup is stored?

Comment: @CodeTrooper If the operating system is linux, its stored in /home/<username>/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this works for me.

```
pg_dump -U postgres <database_name> > <filename.sql> --schema-only
```