# How to clone a database without data in postgres with an SQL request

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am currently working on a project where I need to do an SQL request that can clone a database (postgres) without any data (only schema a.k.a only the columns of the different tables and constraint like primary key/foreign key).

Some topic are similar to my question like this two : [Creating a copy of a database in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876522/creating-a-copy-of-a-database-in-postgresql) and [Backup of PostgreSQL database design - without data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43228951/backup-of-postgresql-database-design-without-data) but they use pg_dump in command line or `TEMPLATE` function that include all data of my orignal DB.

Is there a way of using it in an SQL request or use a specific option of `CREATE DATABASE` to clone without data ? Thank you

Comment: PG_DUMP -s (schema only) there are various commands to determine which elements you need to copy

Comment: No, that cannot be done in SQL. `pg_dump -s` is your best bet. Don't use the `postgres` database to store data in it.