# How to copy Postgres database structure from the server to Oracle Apex installed on my PC?

Tags: oracle-apex

Currently, we have a Postgres database that stores data about users and an application uses it. This database is kept on the application server.
I want to create another application with the help of Oracle Apex and I need to have the same database as a local database. Oracle Apex is installed on my PC.

How can I copy the database structure of that application to use in my application development environment?
Without copying the information of the users in that database, I want to copy only the structure of the database. That is, the tables and their columns.
I use oracle apex 23.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backup of PostgreSQL database design - without data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43228951/backup-of-postgresql-database-design-without-data)